# error upgrading python's packages in centos

Tags: centos, centos7, python, openstack

during update I've got some errors in python's packages

```
Error: Package: python-django-1.8.14-1.el7.noarch (@centos-openstack-ocata)
           Requires: python-django-bash-completion = 1.8.14-1.el7
           Removing: python-django-bash-completion-1.8.14-1.el7.noarch (@centos-openstack-ocata)
               python-django-bash-completion = 1.8.14-1.el7
           Updated By: python-django-bash-completion-1.11.23-1.el7.noarch (epel)
               python-django-bash-completion = 1.11.23-1.el7
           Available: python-django16-bash-completion-1.6.11.7-5.el7.noarch (epel)
               python-django-bash-completion = 1.6.11.7-5.el7
Error: python2-uritemplate conflicts with python2-uri-templates-0.6-5.el7.noarch
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

yum erase python2-uri-templates-0.6-5.el7.noarch

Comment: could you please elaborate why are you recommending this?